# Webview can't load pdf inside html url

Tags: android, pdf, webview

[image]

There is a dialog including pdf file in my url(html). Pdf file keeps showing white like the image I attach above.

I have tried with **"http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url="** but it doesn't work.

I have no idea. Help me:D

Comment: Where is a pdf url?

Comment: It is a book from Office. I have no permission to share it.  

Comment: Do dont need to share anything. Just a fake pdf url would do.